# Inequality random variable and closed balls

Tags: geometry, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable which takes values in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\{X_i\}_i$ be a random sample of $X$. My question is find a constant $C_0\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that
$$
\sup_{x\in B(0,\epsilon)} \left|E\left[|X-x|\right] - \cfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i -x|\right|\leq C_0\left|E[|X|] - \cfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i|\right|,
$$
where $B(0,\epsilon)$ is the closed ball (closed interval) with center $0$ and radius $\epsilon$. The question is find a constant $C_0$ such that we can delete the expression of $x$ in the first part of the inequality.

Thanks in advance.